# Length of comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

New at Python, so please...

Just came across *comprehensions* and I understand that they are soon going to possibly ramify into perhaps dot products or matrix multiplications (although the fact that the result is a set makes them more interesting), but I at this point I want to ask whether there is any formula to determine the length of a comprehension such as:

`{x * y for x in {3, 4, 5} for y in {4, 5, 6}}`.

Evidently I don't mean for this particular one:

`len({x * y for x in {3, 4, 5} for y in {4, 5, 6}}) = 8`, but of any general operation of this type with an element-wise multiplication of two sets, and taking as the result the set of the resultant integers (no repetitions), *for any given length of x and y, consecutive integers, and known x[1] and y[1]*.

I understand that this question is at the crossroads  of coding and math, but I am asking it here on the off chance that it *happened* to be a somewhat common, or well-known computational issue, since I have read that comprehensions are very widely used. It is only in this sense that I am interested in the question. Base on the comments so far, my sense is that this is not the case.

EDIT:

For instance, here is a pattern: If `x = {1, 2, 3}` the `len(x * y)` comprehensions is equal to 9 provided `y[1] = or > 3`. For example, `len({x * y for x in {1, 2, 3} for y in {1111, 1112, 1113}}) = 9`. So tentatively, **length = length(x) * length(y)**, provided there is no overlap in the elements of x and y. Does it work with 4-element sets? Sure: `len({x * y for x in {1, 2, 3, 4} for y in {1111, 1112, 1113, 1114}}) = 16`. In fact, the integers don't need to be consecutive, *just not overlap*: `len({x*y for x in {11,2,39} for y in {3,4,5}}) = 9`.

And, yes, it doesn't work... Check this out:

`{x * y for x in {0, 1, 3} for y in {36, 12, 4}} = {0, 4, 12, 36, 108}`

Comment: This is a pure maths question. Maybe try [math.se].

Comment: Any particular reason you're using set comprehensions instead of list comprehensions? It seems like you might not have noticed the difference.

Comment: @user2357112: Well, the question does say the OP wants no repeats. So `set`s are clearly necessary to guarantee this outcome.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: It seems like the "no repetitions" bit might have been merely describing the situation with set comprehensions, rather than a specifically desired trait.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Particularly, the bit about dot products and matrix multiplication would work way better with list comprehensions, and the tags say "list-comprehension".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible with just the length of the inputs. You can use math to determine the length by computing common prime factors, but the work involved would not improve upon just computing the results and taking the `len` of that, and it requires knowledge of the set contents, not just their length.

After all, with just the length, `{2, 3}` multiplied with `{2, 3}` (producing `{4, 6, 9}`) couldn't be distinguished from `{2, 3}` multiplied with `{10, 11}`, which would produce entirely unique outputs (four total). Makes for a simple proof by contradiction; knowing the input lengths alone is insufficient to determine the length of the output, no single operation on `(2, 2)` can possibly produce both 3 and 4 without additional inputs.

Comment: To be clear, I'm looking for a closed form not with the intention of cutting down computational time, or coding steps, but just to understand better the operations involved in comprehensions. Notice also that I edited the question right at the time your answer came through.

Comment: @AntoniParellada: The answer to your question is "No". The nature of the problem precludes any solution defined solely in the lengths of the inputs.

Comment: Sure. I figured that much, but wanted to keep the question clean at the risk of imprecision. Can I assume that with consecutive integers, knowing the length and the first elements of x and y wouldn't be enough either to calxulated len with a closed mathematical formula?

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, here is a pattern: If x = {1, 2, 3} the len(x * y) comprehensions is equal to 9 provided `y[1] = or > 3`

(I take that you mean `y[1] >= 3` and `y[1]` as the minimum element in the set, because by definition a set don't have order)

for 2 set of size 3 with consecutive elements and empty intersection, that satisfice your condition `y[1]>=3`, here is counter example

```
{x*y for x in {1,2,3} for y in {4,5,6}}
```

Because this are sets, there is always the chance there is less elements that `length(A)*length(B)` and that depend in the content of A and B, but you can find a range to the value

`min(length(A),length(B)) <= length(A*B) <= length(A)*length(B)`

to find the real value of A * B without calculating that, you have to do many more check and that is just much more convoluted that just doing A * B